# Exposing only the interface in WSDL in WCF, rather then the service

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a service contract ICalc, and I want to expose a WSDL through the MEX endpoint, which will only describe the ICalc contract, i.e. will contain only the portType element, without the service element.
Is there a way to do that in WCF?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to expose an abstract WSDL instead of a concrete WSDL. As far as I know, there is no built-in way in WCF to accomplish this.

One thing I thought about is that it may be possible to accomplish this by manually removing the <service> and <binding> elements from the generated WSDL file in a custom [IWsdlExportExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx) extension. However, I was unable to get it to work after a few tests (if I removed the service, WCF would just show the HTML help screen when the WSDL was requested).

There might be a way to get it though, so maybe give it a try.